# Convert Text to Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a text field in Access called `"TempD"`

which contains data like below

```
Mon, Oct 6, 2014 
Mon, Nov 10, 2014
```

I need to convert this to proper date format using SQL and put it in Field `"Emaildate"`

I am using the sql query below:

```
UPDATE MissingT 
SET MissingT.emaildate = format(cdate(Right([tempd],4) & "/" & Mid([tempd],6,3) & "/" & Mid([tempd],9,2)));
```

But the issue is that the TempD field varies in length if the day is single/double. When the day is in 2 digits

```
(Mon, Nov 10, 2014)
```

it is converting this text to `2014-11-01` instead of `2014-11-10`

Any idea how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discard the abbreviated day name, comma, and space from the beginning of your date string ...

```vb
? Mid("Mon, Oct 6, 2014", 5)
 Oct 6, 2014
```

The resulting substring can be converted directly to a Date/Time value using `CDate()` ...

```vb
? CDate(Mid("Mon, Oct 6, 2014", 5))
10/6/2014
```

Then if you want that Date/Time value as a string in *yyyy/mm/dd* format ...

```vb
? Format(CDate(Mid("Mon, Oct 6, 2014", 5)), "yyyy/mm/dd")
2014/10/06
```

If that is what you're after, you can do it in an `UPDATE` query like this ...

```sql
UPDATE MissingT
SET emaildate = Format(CDate(Mid(tempd, 5)), "yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Comment: That worked. My new query is as follows:     UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.emaildate = format(Format(CDate(Mid([tempd], 5)), "yyyy/mm/dd"));

Comment: Do you really have `Format` twice in the expression on the right side of the `=` sign?  That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: IT worked, but I just updated it as this now: UPDATE MissingT SET MissingT.emaildate = format(CDate(Mid([tempd], 5)), "yyyy/mm/dd");

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to apply Format on a date value passed to a Date field.

This is how to solve it:

```
UPDATE 
    MissingT
SET 
    emaildate = DateValue(Mid([tempd], 5))
```

Comment: What makes you think *emaildate* is a Date field?  I concluded it is text because he used `SET MissingT.emaildate = format(...` in his `UPDATE`.

Comment: Because it makes no sense to use another data type than Date for storing date values. If it really is text, the questioneer should change that as the first task of the morning.